# structured streaming writing to multiple streams

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

my Scenario

1. Gets data from a stream and call a UDF which return a json string. one of the attribute in JSON string is UniqueId, which UDF is generating as guid.newGuid() (C#).

   2. DataFrame output of UDF is written to multiple streams/sinks based on some fiter.

issue:

1. each sink is getting a new value for the UniqueId which was generated by UDF. How can i maintain the same UniqueId for all sinks.
2. If each sink is getting different values for UniqueId, does that mean my UDF is getting called multiple times for each sink?
3. If UDF is getting invoked twice, what is the option to get it called once and then just write same data to different sinks

```
inData = spark.readstream().format("eventhub")

udfdata = indata.select(from_json(myudf("column"), schema)).as("result").select(result.*)

filter1 =  udfdata.filter("column =='filter1'")
filter 2 = udfdata.filter("column =='filter2'") 

# write filter1 to two differnt sinks
filter1.writestream().format(delta).start(table1)
filter1.writestream().format(eventhub).start()

# write filter2 to two differnt sinks
filter2.writestream().format(delta).start(table2)
filter2.writestream().format(eventhub).start()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you call `.writestream()....start()` you are creating a new independent streaming query.

This means that for each output sink you define Spark will read again from the input source and process the dataframe.

If you want to read and process only one time and then output to multiple sink you can use **foreachBatch** sink as a workaround:

```py
inData = spark.readstream().format("eventhub")
udfdata = indata.select(from_json(myudf("column"), schema)).as("result").select(result.*)

udfdata.writeStream().foreachBatch(filter_and_output).start()
```

```py
def filter_and_output(udfdata, batchId):
    # At this point udfdata is a batch dataframe, no more a streaming dataframe
    udfdata.cache()
    filter1 = udfdata.filter("column =='filter1'")
    filter2 = udfdata.filter("column =='filter2'") 

    # write filter1
    filter1.write().format(delta).save(table1)
    filter1.write().format(eventhub).save()

    # write filter2
    filter2.write().format(delta).save(table2)
    filter2.write().format(eventhub).save()

    udfdata.unpersist()
```

You can learn more about foreachBatch in the [Spark Structured Streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch).

To answer your questions

1. If you use foreachBatch your data will be processed only once and you will have the same UniqueId for all sinks
2. Yes
3. Using foreachBatch will solve the issue

Comment: Is there any other option, instead of using foreachbatch/foreach? I am using .net for apache spark [C#](https://github.com/dotnet/spark) and looks like presently foreachbatch api is not yet supported.

Comment: does all writequery in spark session will recompute Or only writestream query from same readstream will be computed? in my case can i write result of my UDF to stream(delta lake staging)  and then read from delta lake staging and then do i filter and then write to 2 separate sink?

Comment: Yes, a solution could be to write the result of the UDF temporarily in delta lake and read with a second query. Remember that also in this case if you have multiple sink (`writeStream()`) Spark will read multiple times from delta lake

Comment: thanks my major concern is not executing UDF twice. reading multiple times on UDF staged result is ok in my scenario